# read the contents from html and write in excel sheet in java

Tags: java, html, excel, parsing

Please help me to read a html file and write it in an excel file by using java . I have searched the net , I could get only for copying tables , I need the data in it to be read and write in an excel file .

contents in html file

```html
<title>**Deprecated Method Found**</title>
<h2>**Summary**</h2>
Deprecated API is error-prone and is a potential security threat and thus should not be used.   
<h2>**Description**</h2>
Old API is sometimes marked deprecated because its implementation is designed in a way that can be error-prone. Deprecated API should be avoided where possible.
<h2>**Security Implications**</h2>
Blocks of code that use deprecated API are designed in a careless manner and thus are a potential security threat.
```

I need these separate headings in separate columns and the contents in rows .

Is it possible to parse this html to excel file

Comment: Look at `dom4j` for parsing `xml` and `apachepoi` for creating excel file...

Comment: dom4j or jsoup suggest me which one to use .

Comment: it's really up to u...

Comment: Look at documentation for both and see which one you think u will like better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the HTML using jsoup, a Java HTML Parser. You can then save it as a CSV (Comma separated values) format which can be opened in excel.

#### jsoup to read text after element

Get all `h2` elements using

```
Elements h2s = document.select("h2");
```

Then iterate over the elements reading what the heading says. If this heading is important, use the following code to get the text following that tag.

```
String text = h2.nextSibling().toString();
```

#### Sample CSV opened in Excel:

[image: Sample CSV opened in Excel]

Comment: Thanks harsh , if i need particular tags (for example : summery and description) and neglect some tags(for example :Security Implications) , what should i use .

Comment: Check the edit to the answer. Vote up if you find it useful :) @Suriya